# Need to know if the same ID it's repeated but with a different DATE

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to see if the same "ID" its repeated but with a different "DATE" value.

I was thinking using a numpy.where, so I created the column "Count" to use something like this:

```
df['FULFILL?'] = np.where((df['Count']>1) & (df['DATE']), 'YES', 'NO')
```

But then I got stuck because I was not sure how to end the second condition. Here's an example:

| ID | Count | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 3 | 01/01/2020 |
| 222 | 2 | 02/12/2020 |
| 111 | 3 | 01/01/2020 |
| 222 | 2 | 02/12/2020 |
| 111 | 3 | 02/10/2020 |
| 333 | 2 | 01/25/2020 |
| 333 | 2 | 05/02/2020 |
| 444 | 1 | 01/01/2020 |

I'm looking an output like this:

| ID | Count | DATE | FULFILL? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 3 | 01/01/2020 | YES |
| 222 | 2 | 02/12/2020 | NO |
| 111 | 3 | 01/01/2020 | YES |
| 222 | 2 | 02/12/2020 | NO |
| 111 | 3 | 02/10/2020 | YES |
| 333 | 2 | 01/25/2020 | YES |
| 333 | 2 | 05/02/2020 | YES |
| 444 | 1 | 01/01/2020 | NO |

Sorry if my english it's not very good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
# get number of unique dates per id
s = df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].nunique()
# identify non unique ones
df['FULFILL?'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(s[s>1].index), 'YES', 'NO')
```

Or with both conditions:

```
df['FULFILL?'] = np.where(df['Count'].gt(1) & df['ID'].isin(s[s>1].index),
                          'YES', 'NO')
```

*NB. using an intermediate `s` and `isin`, as it is more efficient than [`groupby.transform('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).*

Output:

```
    ID  Count        DATE FULFILL?
0  111      3  01/01/2020      YES
1  222      2  02/12/2020       NO
2  111      3  01/01/2020      YES
3  222      2  02/12/2020       NO
4  111      3  02/10/2020      YES
5  333      2  01/25/2020      YES
6  333      2  05/02/2020      YES
7  444      1  01/01/2020       NO
```

Count per group:

```
ID
111    2
222    1
333    2
444    1
Name: DATE, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for test number of unique values per groups, first condition `(df['Count']>1)` is removed, because for single value per groups number of unique values is not greater like `1`:

```
df['FULFILL?'] = np.where(df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform('nunique').gt(1), 'YES', 'NO')
print (df)
    ID  Count        DATE FULFILL?
0  111      3  01/01/2020      YES
1  222      2  02/12/2020       NO
2  111      3  01/01/2020      YES
3  222      2  02/12/2020       NO
4  111      3  02/10/2020      YES
5  333      2  01/25/2020      YES
6  333      2  05/02/2020      YES
7  444      1  01/01/2020       NO
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform('nunique'))
0    2
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    1
Name: DATE, dtype: int64
```